# Use changing variable to define range in loop

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, iteration

I would like to extract multiple ranges within a range on a spreadsheet. The number of rows always changing. This is what I'm aiming to do. The start row and the number of rows will always be different.

```
var sourcesheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet name");
var nameRowN = starting rows already in an array
var sor = number of rows in each array already calculated and put in an array

 var ranges = [];
   for (var m = 0; m < sourcesheet.length; m++) {
   ranges = sourcesheet.getRange(nameRowN[m],5,sor[m],29).getValues();
   }
```

So ranges should include multiple mini arrays. The for loop goes through m, then m+1 and so on. 
Am I on the right track? Is that possible to achieve what I'm looking for this way?

**Edit:** I can get the range outside of the loop and replace m variable:

```
ranges = sourcesheet.getRange(nameRowN[1],5,sor[1],29).getValues();
```

Comment: Sheet Class has no length property.

Comment: I had no idea, thank you! I'm quite a beginner with scripts, trying to teach myself while working. Can I use a range instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to iterate through all rows with contents - you can use the method [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow).

Sample:

```
var lastRow=sourcesheet.getLastRow();
for (var m = 0; m < lastRow; m++) {
  //do what you want
}
```

Another possibility would be to use [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()) in conjunction with `getValues()` and `length`.

Sample:

```
var rangeLength=spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues().length;
for (var m = 0; m < rangeLength; m++) {
  //do what you want
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The second method you mentioned was working just as I needed it to. Now it seems so simple yet I couldn't figure it out.